# snap.ref.remove() is removing all the nodes in the parent rather than just itself

Tags: firebase

I was just trying to remove the top 2 nodes, but it removes the entire branch instead.  If I comment out the remove(), it correctly console.logs the top 2 nodes, but when i uncomment the remove() it deletes all the nodes in that messagesRef, not just the top 2.

```
messagesRef.limitToFirst(2).on('child_added', function (snap) {
    snap.ref().remove();
    console.log(snap.val());

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because once you've removed one, there is now a "new" child_added into the limit of 2. So it'll continuously loop through them all until they are all deleted.

```
Child 1
Child 2

->>delete child 1

Child 2
Child 3 ->new child_added event

etc...
```

To get around this you can keep a counter:

```
var numRemoved = 0; 
var ref = messagesRef.limitToFirst(2);
ref.on('child_added', removeFirstTwoChildren);
removeFirstTwoChildren(snap){
    snap.ref().remove();
    console.log(snap.val());
    numRemoved++;
    if(numRemoved === 2){
        ref.off('child_added', removeFirstTwoChildren);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@MatthewBerg's answer will work great. An alternative if you only want to remove a few users is:

```
var ref = messagesRef.limitToFirst(2);
ref.once('value', function(twovaluesnapshot) {
  twovaluesnapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.remove();
  });
});
```

While I generally discourage the use of `once` and `value` for getting lists of items, this seems like a reasonable use-case for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your messagesRef and messagesRef.limitToFirst(2).ref() you may check to see identical path.

What happens when you try the following?

```
messagesRef.limitToFirst(2).on('child_added', function (snap) {
    console.log(snap.val());
    snap.forEach(function(data) {
        console.log("The message key :" + data.key() );
        messagesRef.child(data.key()).remove();
    });
});
```