# Firebase realtime database entries expiration

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to remove old entries from Firebase Database automatically.
Is it possible to configure Firebase to remove old entries for a specific child ?

Comment: I thought  it could be done by add a timestamp each time you insert an entry. And every time Initialize with delete all expired entries in the database. Each time the page is visited, the database will be maintained.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501870/how-to-delete-firebase-data-after-n-days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no API to automatically expire items in the Firebase Database. Such a so-called time-to-live (or ttl) would be an interesting addition, but for the moment you'll have to build it yourself.