# Realtime Database and Storage - Timed delete and Server Side Scripting

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to create an Android app where I need certain data to be removed in the Firebase Realtime Database and File Storage at a certain time.

The data has to be removed at a specific time and date that is set on the client side at first, which is then put into the Realtime database where the data stays there until that date entered, where then the data deletes itself and that set, branch or class of data.

Is it possible to have this kind of scripting on the Realtime database side instead of handling it on the client side? If so, then how do you script something like this?

Comment: Recently came across this post. **Please check:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501870/how-to-delete-firebase-data-after-n-days/37504961#37504961  . This is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Thank You, That is exactly what I was looking for!