# Deleting Firebase data after a certain time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to make this work from

[How to delete firebase data after "n" days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501870/how-to-delete-firebase-data-after-n-days?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but it's not working for me.

Here's what I'm doing,

In my "A" activity, I have a button that will save this chunk of data, with a 'timeStamp' child which holds the timestamp value.
(.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);)

After pressing the button, it saves the data successfully. Then, it starts the next activity, where we wait.

But instead of deleting after '30' days, it deletes it straight away.

I have a method that works exactly like the answer by Frank

```
long cutoff = new Date().getTime() - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(30, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    Query oldBug = mDatabase.orderByChild("timeStamp").endAt(cutoff);
    oldBug.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                itemSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

But it's not deleting it after some time, as soon as it is posted.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

[image: data]

Comment: When I run the code you posted, it behaves as expected.  Export and post a slice of your database that shows the structure and timestamp values.

Comment: @qbix thank you, I put a picture of my data in the question above under EDIT.

Comment: I suspect reference `mDatabase` is not set correctly.  Post the code that defines it.

Comment: @qbix private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); as a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `orderByChild()` sorting method is very forgiving.  The children being sorted are not required to have a member with the specified field name.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#data-order) explains that those children are assigned a null value and appear first in the sort.  Thus, if the reference used to create a query is incorrectly located, the query doesn't fail and instead will typically return all the children of that location.

You created your `oldBug` query using `mDatabase` where:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

This is one level too high.  It should be:

```
 Query oldBug = mDatabase.child("Users").orderByChild("timeStamp").endAt(cutoff);
```

Comment: Thank you, this did it! By the way, I have a minor problem. How can I get it so that it deletes in real-time?

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by "in real-time".

Comment: For example, if I set the data to be deleted after 5 minutes, it should delete the data EXACTLY at 5 minutes. Not 5 minutes and until refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might consider making a new child item that has a timestamp and date so that you can reference back to it when doing a query for the date and time. This way you don't have to worry about incorrect values and you can ensure you are deleting the correct data. I hope this helps.