# Delete a set of firebase data automatically after assigned time has passed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, epoch

I have some data in `FirebaseDatabase` in which every data set has two properties: `startTime` and `endTime`.

Here's the data-structure:

```
app
 -ref
   -uniqueID1
     -key: value
     -startTime: 1488849333
     -endTime: 1488853842
     -key: value
   -uniqueID2
     -key: value
     -startTime: 1488850198
     -endTime: 1488853802
     -key: value
```

**What I want** is to deleted the data set when the `endTime` has passed automatically or when the user opens the app.

I have done some research on this topic and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37504961/6144372), but this doesn't seems helpful to me.

**How can I** remove the datasets whose `endTime` has passed?

Comment: I dont think firebase-database does have automatic script to do that. You may need a backend script to do this job. or you may check nexttime when you fetch the data. If the end time expires then delete that and dont show it to the user.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @user1077539

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a similar answere but you seem not to understand the answer. So here is how to do it.
Since what matters is the end time only we are going to monitor when it has passed. To do this, we  get the current time

```
Date().getTime();
```

and check whether its greater than the end time(if it is, it means that the end time has passed)

```
final DatabaseReference currentRef = adapter.getRef(position);
                    currentRef.child("endTime").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();  //get time in millis
                            long end = Long.parseLong( dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()); //get the end time from firebase database

                            //convert to int
                            int timenow = (int) time; 
                            int endtime = (int) end;

                            //check if the endtime has been reached
                            if (end < time){
                                currentRef.removeValue();  //remove the entry
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

i have implemented that code when the item i want to remove is clicked. so the adapter is from a listview. 
Thanks, i hope it helps