# how to delete a node in firebase 8 hours after its creation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an android app in which every node should be deleted after 8 hours of its creation. whenever the new node is being created it is saved in firebase real-time database and firestore. now I want every node to get deleted automatically from  FireBase database after 8 hours how can I do this thing ??

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42796988/7201671) out.

Comment: From Android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501870/how-to-delete-firebase-data-after-n-days From Cloud Functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours