# Deleting firebase data after 'n' days but in reference to server time

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to do similar things like in this post:
[How to delete firebase data after "n" days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501870/how-to-delete-firebase-data-after-n-days)
But the solution given there allows user to delete everything from database by changing the date on his phone.

How to deleting firebase data after 'n' days but not in reference to the time set by the user.

Where can I get "a safe time" which couldn't be changed by the user of app?

Comment: Try using cron job

Comment: You are using Firebase realtime database or Cloud Firestore?