# Is there a way to set Firestore data to autodelete after 'n' days for Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a flutter app that requires certain information to be accessible to all users for 5 days before automatically being cleared off the database.

is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501870/how-to-delete-firebase-data-after-n-days , you can also accomplish that with functions, this will be more relevant

Comment: could you add any material for functions. The previous material clears all the data as my execution is wrapped by an iterative for loop

Comment: I edited your question to give you an answer, I don't understand why your question was closed

Comment: Is it possible to share a link or email me at justinivor20@gmail.com