# Impelementing aging in a Firebase real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Unfortunately, Firebase doesn't have out of the box an aging mechanism (delete old entries automatically). So, I am trying to implement one. However, I am stuck between two decisions:

1. If a client fetch an old entry, he will delete automatically: I
   think it is the easiest for my context, but it doesn't look very
   secure to me.
2. Implement a small script/program on a server that will
   check the full database and delete old entries.

I like the first solution, since it doesn't include deploying another server side application but I don't know if it could represent a risk.

What do you think is the best ? 
How can I secure the first solution to avoid any possible deletion of all items ? 
For the second solution, I don't won't to run the script from my computer and I don't want to pay for another sever to deploy the script, it it possible to to deploy it on Firebase ?

Comment: The answers on this post may give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990681/firebase-chat-removing-old-messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting outdated items from the client has been covered before. See:

- [Firebase chat - removing old messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990681/firebase-chat-removing-old-messages)
- [How to delete firebase data after "n" days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501870/how-to-delete-firebase-data-after-n-days/37504961#37504961)
- [Delete firebase data older than 2 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours/32012520#32012520)

To secure this operation so that only outdated items can be removed, you can use [Firebase Database security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#structuring_your_rules). Something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$message": {
        // only messages older than an hours can be remove
        ".write": "newData.exists() || data.child('timestamp').val() < (now - 3600000)",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running your own code on Firebase's servers can now be done with [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). There is also a [sample that shows how to delete older data with Cloud Functions](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-old-child-nodes).