# Firebase Firestore auto message deletion after set time

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

is there a way or method like with Firebase rules or something to set auto-deletion of documents that are aged past 24 hours of the creation time? It's for a chat application using the React framework. What would be the best method for this?

Edit; sorry if the question is bad or missing context, ive never really asked on here but this one really has me scratching my head recently. Feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: [You can find your solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50952928/16148023)

Comment: AH ok this is what i was looking for, thank you!